# Shiny Server - For the open source shiny server, is there a way to check if the connection is taken?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

As far as I know, that Shiny Server Open Source can only support one concurrent user at a time. So I am wondering, is there a way to check if this server is serving for a user at the moment so that I can redirect the user to another page?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can open as much sessions as you want using Shiny Server Open Source..

Comment: @Ika8, sorry if I misunderstood something. For example, if one user is using Shiny computing something, the other user cannot open Shiny. Is there a way to check that currently the Shiny app is being used by other people?

Comment: If you are running shiny server open source (on ubuntu for example) there is no limit of people connected and using the service...

Comment: @Ika8,hmmm..., but from what I see in the app, if a computation is going on(approximately cost 2 minutes to finish), the other user cannot open the shiny app during computing until it finishes.

Comment: can you please share your server function?